# MySQL Error 150

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

I'm trying to create a script to normalize another table in MySQL. Below is what I have:

```
USE  hw7;

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_codes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_locations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_codenames;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

CREATE TABLE airport_codes(
airport_code char(3) not null,
airline_code char(2) not null,
primary key (airport_code, airline_code)
);

INSERT INTO airport_codes SELECT DISTINCT airport_code, airline_code 
    FROM airport_airlines;

CREATE TABLE airport_locations(
airport_code char(3) not null,
city varchar(20) not null,
state char(2) not null,
primary key (airport_code),
constraint ap_code_fk
    foreign key (airport_code)
    references airport_codes(airport_code)
);

INSERT INTO airport_locations SELECT DISTINCT airport_code, city, state 
    FROM airport_airlines;

CREATE TABLE airport_codenames(
airline_code char(2) not null,
name varchar(20) not null,
primary key (airline_code),
constraint al_code_fk
    foreign key (airline_code)
    references airport_codes(airline_code)
);

INSERT INTO airport_codenames SELECT DISTINCT airline_code, name 
    FROM airport_airlines;
```

This code results in this error:

> Can't create table hw7.airport_codenames errno:150

Comment: These FK relationships seem backwards. Typically, `airport_codenames` would be the primary table, and `airport_codes` would have the FK into `airport_codenames`. Likewise, `airport_locations` would be the PK table, with an FK in `airport_codes`. Both of them seem backward...

Comment: I was asuming the following functional dependencies:

Airport_code>city, state
Airline_code>name

Comment: But if you permit multiple  `airline_code` per `airport_code`s in `airport_locations` (by composite key), that breaks the foreign key from `airport_codenames` since it would point to multiple rows in `airport_locations`.  I think that's the source of your problem.

Comment: So what is the code that you recommend?

Comment: I put it in as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `airport_codes` has multiple possible rows per `airport_code` and `airline_code` (as a composite key), it cannot be referenced by other foreign keys. Move the FK relationships into `airport_codes`, pointing to `airport_locations` and `airport_codenames`.

```
USE  hw7;

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_codes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_locations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_codenames;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;


CREATE TABLE airport_locations(
airport_code char(3) not null,
city varchar(20) not null,
state char(2) not null,
primary key (airport_code)
);

INSERT INTO airport_locations SELECT DISTINCT airport_code, city, state 
    FROM airport_airlines;

CREATE TABLE airport_codenames(
airline_code char(2) not null,
name varchar(20) not null,
primary key (airline_code)
);

INSERT INTO airport_codenames SELECT DISTINCT airline_code, name 
    FROM airport_airlines;


/* airport_codes moved after the other 2 tables, and FKs defined here */
CREATE TABLE airport_codes(
airport_code char(3) not null,
airline_code char(2) not null,
primary key (airport_code, airline_code),
/* FK relationships are defined here, rather than in the other tables,
   since the PKs for airport_code and airline_code are defined in the
   other tables.
*/
constraint ap_code_fk
    foreign key (airport_code)
    references airport_locations (airport_code),
constraint al_code_fk
    foreign key (airline_code)
    references airport_codenames (airline_code)
);

INSERT INTO airport_codes SELECT DISTINCT airport_code, airline_code 
    FROM airport_airlines;
```

Comment: Oh I see now. This makes much more sense than what I was trying. Thank you so much for all your help! I wish I could rep you up more than once. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It should come from you drop table order. Like mysql doc say

> InnoDB does not permit you to drop a table that is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint, unless you do SET foreign_key_checks = 0

So set the foreign key check rightfully or change your drop order in:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_locations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_codenames;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_codes;
```

You drop foreign key before the reference.

Comment: Um, read the code above again.  `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` happens right before the tables are dropped.

Comment: Sorry my bad, was looking for your foreign key reference

Comment: Like Micheal said, I think I have that part of my script correct. Thanks for trying though. I still can't figure this out.

Comment: Copy paste from mysql doc: If MySQL reports an error number 1005 from a CREATE TABLE statement, and the error message refers to error 150, table creation failed because a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed. Similarly, if an ALTER TABLE fails and it refers to error 150, that means a foreign key definition would be incorrectly formed for the altered table. You can use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to display a detailed explanation of the most recent InnoDB foreign key error in the server.